# How can I call function with parameter in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a function that I used for testing software. I have to call this function where the function have 2 parameters, that is currentSetName and failureDetected. This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

failureDetected=0 
nbOfAllTests=0
nbOfDetectedFailures=0`
currentSetName="fair"
count_input=1

removeFromCurrentSet(){
if [[("$1" == "good")]]
  then 
      #mv Partition/currentSet/* Partition/good_used
      echo "Hai good"

  elif [[("$1" == "fair")]]
  then
        if [[("$2" == "0")]]
        then
            #mv Partition/currentSet/* Partition/poor_used
            echo "hai fair poor_used"
        else 
            #mv Partition/currentSet/* Partition/good_used
            echo "hai fair good"
        fi
else

            #mv Partition/currentSet/* Partition/poor_used
            echo "jjj poor"

fi
}

removeFromCurrentSet currentSetName failureDetected
```

I use the code above but it's not work well. Can you help me for the problem? how can I call the function exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incorrectly passing the arguments. Your original code is equivalent to

```
removeFromCurrentSet "currentSetName" "failureDetected"
```

just passing two strings, because `currentSetName` and  `failureDetected` are not expanded. You need to expand the variables first using `$`.

To pass to the function the values of your variables try this instead:

```
removeFromCurrentSet "${currentSetName}" "${failureDetected}"
```

Comment: Curly braces are only necessary if characters around the `$` + variable expression would otherwise be interpreted as being part of it.

Comment: thank you @jotik it's solved my problem. sorry i haven't said before